# Generate dynamic HTML table by looping through DataTable on webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, webforms

I want to populate an html table with the data I got from the code behind of a webform page.

This is how I have done it.
This is the code behind where I have collected a DataTable data from the database.

```
private void Page_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   GetDataTable()
}
protected DataTable GetDataTable()
{
     DataTable tableData = EnterpriseDB.HospitalPage("DentalHospitalView", CompanyID, DivisionID, DepartmentID, "Orthopaedics", "TypeID", "*");
     return tableData;
}
```

This is the webform where the data is used to create a dynamic table.

```html
<table  class="table" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                
                                <th scope="col">State</th>
                                <th scope="col">NAME</th>
                                <th scope="col">ADDRESS</th>
                                <th scope="col">TELEPHONE</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                             <% foreach (System.Data.DataRow dt in this.GetDataTable().Rows) { %>
                            <tr>
                                
                                <td><h2><% dt["EmployeeState"].ToString(); %></h2></td>
                                <td><% dt["EmployeeName"].ToString(); %></td>
                                <td><% dt["EmployeeAddress1"].ToString(); %></td>
                                <td><% dt["EmployeePhone"].ToString(); %></td>

                            </tr>
                            <% } %>
                        </tbody>
                        
                    </table >
```

The problem is when load the page I get an empty table.
What have I done wrong please?
Thanks.

Comment: can you share the code of the method `HospitalPage`?

Comment: I will, but the thing is when I debugged, it showed that there is data in the returned value. and the "GetDataTable()" method returns the data, so I'm sure that is not the issue.

Comment: in this case, check if you have the same columns name in the DataTable. `EmployeeState`, `EmployeeName` etc. and delete dot in `dt.["EmployeeState"].ToString();` should be like `dt["EmployeeState"].ToString();`

Comment: yes that was a mistake when I was typing. And I'm still wondering what I'm doing wrong because I do have those columns.

Comment: Well, we're only going to be able to guess randomly without more information, which is a waste of both your time and ours. I'm not sure why you don't just use a `GridView` control though, as it would take care of everything for you...

Comment: Try to add `foreach (System.Data.DataRow dt in this.GetDataTable().Rows)
 Debug.WriteLine(dt["EmployeeState"].ToString());` in `GetDataTable` method, and check the outputin VS.

Comment: @hereticmonkey no I don't want to use grid view for aesthetic purpose.